# How to avoid integer overflow in MiniZinc?

Tags: python, constraints, overflow, minizinc, morse-code

I am trying to solve a code-game from codingame website using MiniZinc for Python.
All I have to do is to find the number of the possible combination in a morse code, given a vocabulary (a set of possible words that, converted and concatenated, should precisely be equal to the input morse code).
I have been able to sort out a solution pretty fast, but the problem is that whatever solver I use, I get an integer overflow.
I tried to use OptiMathSAT but I could not manage to apply it.

Here, you can find my code (you will not find the count of the possible combination, but I think it would be straigth-forward):

```
MORSE_CODE_DICT = { 'A':'12', 'B':'2111', 
                    'C':'2121', 'D':'211', 'E':'1', 
                    'F':'1121', 'G':'221', 'H':'1111', 
                    'I':'11', 'J':'1222', 'K':'212', 
                    'L':'1211', 'M':'22', 'N':'21', 
                    'O':'222', 'P':'1221', 'Q':'2212', 
                    'R':'121', 'S':'111', 'T':'2', 
                    'U':'112', 'V':'1112', 'W':'122', 
                    'X':'2112', 'Y':'2122', 'Z':'2211'}


# Input vocabulary converter to number
def converter(vocabulary):
    for i in range(len(vocabulary)):
        var = ""
        for j in vocabulary[i]:
            var = var+MORSE_CODE_DICT[j]
        vocabulary[i]=int(var)
    return vocabulary

# Create a MiniZinc model

gecode = Solver.lookup("or-tools")
model=Model()
model.add_string("""
include "globals.mzn";

int: n;
int: lmax;
array[1..n] of int: c;
int: morse;
array [1..lmax] of var 1..n: frase; 
var int: r;
array [1..n] of var int: len;
array [1..lmax] of var int: sa;

constraint forall(i in 1..n)(len[i]=string_length(mzn_version_to_string(c[i]))-4);
constraint sa[1]=c[frase[1]]; 
constraint forall(i in 2..lmax)(sa[i]=c[frase[i]]*pow(10,sum(j in 2..i)(len[frase[j-1]]))); 
constraint lmax>0 /\ lmax<100000;
constraint n>0 /\ n<100000;
constraint forall(i in len)(i>0 /\ i<20);
constraint r>=0 /\ r<pow(2,10);
constraint sum(sa) = morse;
""")

# Transform Model into a instance

inst = Instance(gecode, model)
inst["n"] = 6

vocabulary = ["HELL","HELLO","OWORLD","WORLD","TEST"]
vocabulary= np.array(converter(vocabulary))
vocabulary = np.append(vocabulary, 0)
print(vocabulary)
inst["c"] = vocabulary

morse = 11111121112112221222221211211211
inst["morse"] = morse

print(len(str(morse)));
inst["lmax"] = len(str(morse))

result = inst.solve()
```

How would you solve this problem? Could you give me some advice about a possible solution or different approach to the problem?
I have already tried using strings rather than ints, but MiniZinc does not support them very well.

Thank you in advance to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Most FlatZinc solvers don't support large integers and give overlflow errors, for example when detecting operations with integers larger than 2**32. The exact limit is solver dependent.

One problem in your model is that you have a lot of domains defined as `var int` which yield very large domains for the solver to work with. If you try to reduce these domains as much as possible, it might work.

In the MiniZinc model, I commented some of the constraints and gave all the `var int` some (but probably wrong) domains which gave a solution using the OR-tools solver:

```
include "globals.mzn";

int: n;
int: lmax;
array[1..n] of int: c;
int: morse;

array [1..lmax] of var 1..n: frase; 
var 0..pow(2,10): r; % hakank
array [1..n] of var 0..20: len; % hakank
array [1..lmax] of var 0..100000000: sa; % hakank

% constraint forall(i in 1..n)(len[i]=string_length(mzn_version_to_string(c[i]))-4);
constraint sa[1]=c[frase[1]]; 
% constraint forall(i in 2..lmax)(sa[i]=c[frase[i]]*pow(10,sum(j in 2..i)(len[frase[j-1]]))); 
constraint lmax>0 /\ lmax<100000;
% constraint n>0 /\ n<100000;
% constraint forall(i in len)(i>0 /\ i<20);
% constraint r>=0 /\ r<pow(2,10);
constraint sum(sa) = morse;

solve satisfy;
```

Here is one solution which - as mentioned above - don't look correct. But you can now work with the constraints and the domains.

```
Solution(frase=[5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
         r=0, 
         len=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
         sa=[211112, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 47272535, 100000000, 100000000, 100000000, 100000000, 100000000, 100000000, 100000000, 100000000, 100000000, 100000000, 100000000, 100000000, 100000000, 100000000, 100000000, 100000000, 100000000, 100000000, 100000000, 100000000, 100000000],    
         _checker='')
```